# How to calculate the percentage of total area of features having specific attributes' values with Qgis?

Tags: attributes, percentage, area, qgis

I'm working in QGis with different layers covering the same geographical extent. Taking the intersection of those layers, I generated a new one whose attribute table contains all the attributes from the different layers. I would then like to know if there is a tool in Qgis that would allow me to generate the percentage areas covered by features corresponding to specific attributes' value. Would it be possible to compare for example the areas in percentages of the features caracterised by value A and Value B of Attibute 1 and 2 with the one of the features caracterised by value C and D of the same attributes?

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards,